# Created directory initially invisible

Tags: java, android, file-io

My app creates a directory on the device, but this directory is not visible/accessible via USB until I reboot the device. Is there any way to make this directory visible and accessible via USB immediately, even if the device is connected (obviously not if it's on an SD card)? If not, how can I make it visible as soon as the user connects a device via USB?

```
storageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyDir");
boolean mkdirsResult = storageDirectory.mkdirs();
```

The directory gets created no problem and is visible via a file manager on the device, just not via USB which is what I need.

Comment: Have you tried another device? I did not have this problem.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are creating the directory?

Comment: I haven't tried another device, don't have one at hand at the moment. It's a Nexus 4 so it should in theory work as Android is supposed to work.

Comment: What do you mean by `via USB` ? Is it mounted as MTP or camera device ? or do you mean you can't pull file over usb via `adb pull` ?

Comment: Says it's connected as a media device. And I can't see the directory I created until I reboot the device.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by calling `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` on the created directory/file immediately after creating it.